# How to generate new variables from multiline variables in R

Tags: r

This is the data:

```
a =  c(1,0,0,NA,0,1)
b =  c(0,1,0,NA,NA,0)
c =  c(0,1,0,NA,NA,NA)
cbind(a,b,c) -> df
```

I want to generate a variable named `x`. It needs the following requirements:

1. As long as there is one ‘1’ in the three lines, `x` is ‘1’; otherwise `x` is ‘0’.
2. Only when all three lines are missing and does not have a ‘1’, `x` is returned as a missing value, `NA`.

```
df
      a  b  c      x
[1,]  1  0  0      1
[2,]  0  1  1      1
[3,]  0  0  0      0
[4,] NA NA NA      NA
[5,]  0 NA NA      NA
[6,]  1  0 NA      1
```

Comment: did you try [`case_when()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when)

Answer (score 2):

We can write a custom function to check each row of the data. Apply the function to each row using `apply`.

```
check_row <- function(x) {
  #Return 1 if any value is 1
  if(any(x == 1, na.rm = TRUE)) return(1)
  #return 0 if all the values are 0
  if(all(x %in% 0)) return(0)
  #else return NA
  else NA
}

df <- cbind(df, x = apply(df, 1, check_row))
df

#      a  b  c  x
#[1,]  1  0  0  1
#[2,]  0  1  1  1
#[3,]  0  0  0  0
#[4,] NA NA NA NA
#[5,]  0 NA NA NA
#[6,]  1  0 NA  1
```

Answer (score 2):

To have vectorized code use logical vectors.

```r
a =  c(1,0,0,NA,0,1)
b =  c(0,1,0,NA,NA,0)
c =  c(0,1,0,NA,NA,NA)
cbind(a,b,c) -> df

ones <- rowSums(df == 1, na.rm = TRUE)
x <- ones > 0
is.na(x) <- rowSums(is.na(df)) > 0 & ones == 0
rm(ones)
cbind(df, x)
#>       a  b  c  x
#> [1,]  1  0  0  1
#> [2,]  0  1  1  1
#> [3,]  0  0  0  0
#> [4,] NA NA NA NA
#> [5,]  0 NA NA NA
#> [6,]  1  0 NA  1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `dplyr` option, where we can convert to a dataframe, then use `case_when` to apply your requirements, then covert back to a matrix.

```
library(dplyr)

as.data.frame(df) %>%
  mutate(x = rowSums(across(everything()), na.rm = T),
         x = case_when(x >= 1 ~ 1,
                   x == 0 & if_any(everything(), is.na) ~ NA_real_,
                   TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  as.matrix.data.frame()
```

**Output**

```
      a  b  c  x
[1,]  1  0  0  1
[2,]  0  1  1  1
[3,]  0  0  0  0
[4,] NA NA NA NA
[5,]  0 NA NA NA
[6,]  1  0 NA  1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think  we can simply do:

```
df %>% 
  as_data_frame() %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(x = ifelse(any(c_across(a:c) == 1), 1, 0))
```

```
      a     b     c     x
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0     0     1
2     0     1     1     1
3     0     0     0     0
4    NA    NA    NA    NA
5     0    NA    NA    NA
6     1     0    NA     1
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `if_any`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(x = +(if_any(everything(), ~ .x == 1)))
```

-output

```
   a  b  c  x
1  1  0  0  1
2  0  1  1  1
3  0  0  0  0
4 NA NA NA NA
5  0 NA NA NA
6  1  0 NA  1
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
cbind(df, x = +(do.call(pmax, data.frame(df)) | rowSums(df, TRUE) > 0))

      a  b  c  x
[1,]  1  0  0  1
[2,]  0  1  1  1
[3,]  0  0  0  0
[4,] NA NA NA NA
[5,]  0 NA NA NA
[6,]  1  0 NA  1
```